# Sobreescritura en for anidados

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

Estoy tratando de realizar, una **asignación** de una lista con fechas a otra lista, estas fechas, están en formato string. El código es el siguiente:

```
lista_fechas = ['2021-03-23',
 '2021-03-24',
 '2021-03-25',
 '2021-03-26',
 '2021-03-27',
 '2021-03-28',
 '2021-03-29',
 '2021-03-30',
 '2021-03-31',
 '2021-04-01',
 '2021-04-02',
 '2021-04-03',
 '2021-04-04',
 '2021-04-05',
 '2021-04-06',
 '2021-04-07',
 '2021-04-08',
 '2021-04-09',
 '2021-04-10',
 '2021-04-11',
 '2021-04-12']

particiones_2 = [
 ('../ruta/2021-03-16',
  datetime.date(2021, 3, 16)),
 ('../2021-03-22',
  datetime.date(2021, 3, 22)),
 ('../2021-03-29',
  datetime.date(2021, 3, 29)),
 ('../2021-04-05',
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 5)),
 ('../2021-04-12',
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 12))]

for i in range(len(particiones_2)):
    for f in range(len(lista_fechas)):
        if lista_fechas[f] in str(particiones_2[i][1]):
            print(lista_fechas[f])
```

Normalmente da este **output** en el print:

> ```
> 2021-03-29
> 2021-04-05
> 2021-04-12
> ```

Sin embargo, cuando hago una asignación, buscando almacenar en una lista estas 3 fechas que cumplen el criterio del if. Me da error.

[image: Captura de pantalla]
La **salida** deseada o esperada sería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna sugerencia para resolver este problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error no está en el código que estás compartiendo, sino que es visible en la captura de pantalla donde muestras el código real.

Específicamente el problema es (como bien te indica IPython):

```
fechas_load[f] = lista_fechas[f]
```

Cuando haces eso, estás intentando asignar un valor a una posición inexistente de la lista vacía `fechas_load`. De eso se queja Python. Lo que quieres hacer en realidad es:

```
fechas_load.append(lista_fechas[f])
```

Ahora bien, solucionado el error, tu código quedaría así (con algunos toques más *pythonics*)

```py
fechas_load = []
for fecha in lista_fechas:
    for particion in particiones_2:
        if fecha == str(particion[1]):
            fechas_load.append(fecha)
            continue
```

O usando comprehensión de listas:

```py
fechas_load = [
    fecha
    for fecha in lista_fechas
    if any(str(particion[1]) == fecha for particion in particiones_2)
]
```